# Create one column from time and quantity

Tags: python, r, excel, vba, excel-formula

Is there a way in excel, Python, or R to convert data that is in the format of time and quantity per date into one long column. For instance:

Current format:

[image]

Instead I want this data to be one long column of 17 0s followed by 1 1 and 176 0s etc.

Thank you in advance for any help.

To elaborate the data looks like this:

Current data:

[image]

And I need this data to look like this:

Final result:

[image]

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and not as images. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

One option with `uncount`

```
 library(tidyr)
 uncount(dat, quantity)
```

---

Or with `rep`

```
with(dat, rep(time, quantity))
```

Comment: This hasn't worked for me. I have added further information to my post